# Selecting interesting graph positions with a button press/click or something similar

Tags: plotting, graphics, function-construction, filtering

Assume that I have a `graphList` as shown below (a simple working example).

```
graphList = 
  Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3.5}], 
     ListPlot[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, #], 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, PointSize[0.05]]], 
     PlotLabel -> Style[#, Red, Bold, 20]] & /@ Range[10];
```

[image]

Now, imagine that I want to manually go through each graph one by one and save interesting graphs by positions into separate lists. For example:

```
interestingList1 = {1, 3, 8};
interestingList2 = {4, 6};
```

However, I don't want to manually write down the numbers like that, as it is easy to make errors by miswriting the numbers and it's probaly a bit slow as well. So, I'm thinking about a method to add something to the graph (button or something) that allows me to save positions by simply clicking/pressing a button or using a similar method to add them to `interestingList1` and `interestingList2`, which I can select.
A button is just my idea. If you know a better way to do it, please suggest as well.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You may store the different plots and then use "AppendTo" to fill the list with the chosen plots like:

```
graphList = {}; 
Column[{graph[#] = 
     Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3.5}], 
      ListPlot[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, #], 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, PointSize[0.05]]], 
      PlotLabel -> Style[#, Red, Bold, 20]], 
    Button["Save", AppendTo[graphList, graph[#]]]}] & /@ Range[10]

Dynamic[graphList]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can use a combination of [`SetterBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetterBar.html), [`TogglerBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TogglerBar.html) and [`PaneSelector`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PaneSelector.html)

```
ClearAll[tB, indexSelector]

tB[Dynamic[$w_], gl_, nc_ : 5] := TogglerBar[Dynamic[$w], 
   Thread[Range[Length @ gl] -> gl], 
   Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, nc}]

SetAttributes[indexSelector, HoldFirst]

indexSelector[intl_, graphlst_, nc_ : 5] := (ClearAll @ intl;
   Deploy @ 
   DynamicModule[{$z, $il = Range @ Length @ intl, lbls = ToString /@ intl}, 
    Column[{SetterBar[Dynamic[$z], MapThread[Rule, {$il, lbls}]], 
      PaneSelector[
        Table[With[{$w = intl[[$i]]}, tB[Dynamic[$w], graphlst, nc]], 
         {$i, 1, Length @ intl}], 
        Dynamic[$z]]}, 
      Alignment -> Center]])
```

***Examples:***

```
graphList = Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3.5}], 
  ListPlot[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, #], 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, PointSize[0.05]]],
  PlotLabel -> Style[#, Red, Bold, 20]] & /@ Range[10];


indexSelector[{interestingList1, interestingList2, interestingList3}, 
  graphList]

Dynamic[{interestingList1, interestingList2, interestingList3}]
```

[image]

For more responsive interaction, rasterize the graphics in `graphList`:

```
rasterizedGraphList = Rasterize[#, ImageResolution -> 100, Background -> None, 
     ImageSize -> 180] & /@ graphList;


indexSelector[{interestingList1, interestingList2, interestingList3}, 
  rasterizedGraphList, 4]

Dynamic[{interestingList1, interestingList2, interestingList3}]
```

[image]

```
Dynamic @ Style[Multicolumn[graphList[[interestingList2]], 2], 
  ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]